# ScaleTransform no effect when in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `ScaleTransform` to change the size of a `UserControl` on a `Canvas`. It works perfectly until I use the ItemsControl Control.

The problem is that I need the scaling to be centered, the `UserControl` should not "move". As soon as it is inside the `ItemsControl`, the item Scales on `Position` x=0, y=0 instead of the center.

Would be great to know what I am doing wrong!

Here is some XAML showing it does not work (there is a single item in DataSource, nothing special it only displays a red rectangle on the window).

```
// This slider is used to scale the Grid inside the ItemsControl.
<Slider x:Name="pointResizeSlider" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="7" Value="1"/>

// The items Control.
<ItemsControl Name="icTest"  Background="Blue" Width="200" Height="200">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    // For simplicity I am using a simple 100x100 Grid. This will get scaled.
                    <Grid Margin="0 0 5 5"  Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red">
                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform 

                                    // This would make it pretty obvious, if it would work. 
                                    // Shows no effect.
                                    CenterX="1000"  
                                    CenterY="1000"  
                                    ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=pointResizeSlider}"  
                                    ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=pointResizeSlider}" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**

Using `RenderTransform` works in this case, but I have to calculate the `ActualSize` of the `UserControl` (which does not work right now with `RenderTransform`). Why does `LayoutTransform` not work in this case?

Comment: Did you try to set the RenderTransformOrigin property?

Comment: yes it is set and does not change anything. It is pretty weird. Anyways I have a workaround using the RenderTransform and doing some maths calculating the Size it should be. Still not optimal.